# Add current time before log message

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, timestamp, logging

I created a custom logger for my application, called CRON_LOG, just by adding this piece of code to config/environment.rb

```
CRON_LOG = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/cron.log")
CRON_LOG.level = Logger::INFO
```

And then, when I want to log something, just do that:

```
CRON_LOG.info "something"
```

It works fine, but I'd like to add the current timestamp before each log message. Of course I can just add `Time.now` to my log message, but I'd like to know if there is a way to add it as default to every log message. How can I do that ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 43):

The easiest way to make a SysLog-formatted logger is to assign a formatter directly:

```
logger = Logger.new Rails.root.join('path', 'to', 'log')
logger.formatter = Logger::Formatter.new
logger.info 'Hello, world!'
# Writes:
#
#   I, [2011-06-02T20:02:34.579501 #15444]  INFO -- : Hello, world!
```

Answer (score 8):

You can redefine the proper method (e.g. adding the following to `environment.rb` or in an initializer):

```
class Logger
  def format_message(severity, timestamp, progname, msg)
    "#{timestamp} (#{$$}) #{msg}\n"
  end
end
```

[Caution: this could disrupt other loggers; see Stephen's answer for a safe solution - jph]

Comment: Accept it as an answer if it worked, so other people with the same problem will spot it immediately in the future. :-)

Comment: I've added a less-invasive way of handling this. In any case, I'd recommend subclassing `Logger` or redefining `format_message` on the instance if you plan on overloading the method to avoid modifying the behavior of other active loggers at runtime.