# Rails 5 TaggedLogging - Wanting to display Severety and timestamp in log

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to get Rails logging to display the timestamp and the severity (DEBUG, INFO, WARNING, etc) with using TaggedLogging. In my application.rb file I have:

`config.logger = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(Logger.new('log/file/location.log'))`

I have also looked at [Add current time before log message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5173007/add-current-time-before-log-message) for a possible solution. However, when i try the solution given by stephencelis, I get a white server error page.

I would ideally like to continue to use TaggedLogging in this case. Any advice or help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6):

By default ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging uses minimal formatter, that's why there no timestamp and log levels written. But you can use your own formatter. 
I use default rails log formatter in example.

```
my_logger           = Logger.new(STDOUT)
my_logger.formatter = Logger::Formatter.new
tagged_logger       = ActiveSupport::TaggedLogging.new(my_logger)

tagged_logger.tagged('MY_TAG') { tagged_logger.debug 'debugging under my_tag.' }
=> 'D, [2018-02-19T15:22:40.905304 #16385] DEBUG -- : [MY_TAG] debugging under my_tag.'
```

For more see [this](https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/keeping-your-logs-from-becoming-an-unreadable-mess/) article and comments